# Replace certain matrix elements with zeros in Maxima

Tags: matrix, replace, element, moodle, maxima

I'm trying to change the elements of a matrix hat are equal to `und` into zeros. I tried accomplishing this with a matrix map but it didn't work:

```
und_to_zero(element) := block( [], if ( is( element = und ) then element : 0 ) else (  ) );
Ma : matrix([25,40,0,und,und],[und,und,15,20,20]);
MaCalc : copymatrix(Ma);
MaCalc: matrixmap(und_to_zero, MaCalc);
```

This throws a `check maxima connection` error on Moodle. My guess is that the problem is with my conditional construction in the definition of the function `und_to_zero`, but I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.

Can anyone spot the error for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a briefer way to achieve the same effect is to say `MaCalc: subst(und = 0, Ma)`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you actually have to specify what you want to accomplish in the `else` branch:

```
und_to_zero(element) := block( [], if  is( element = und ) then element : 0  else element:element );
```

Comment: That function can be made a little more concise. (1) `block([], ...)` has no effect since there is only 1 expression in the function body. (2) `if is(...) ...` is equivalent to `if ...` (i.e. `is` is unneeded after `if`). (3) `if` is an expression with a value, not a command with a side effect. So no need to assign to `element`. All together: `und_to_zero(element) := if element = und then 0 else element`.